# How to identify a particular text box?

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox, word-2013

My VBA routine is deigned to alter text in a text box in the document's footer. Right now it is identified as follows:

```
Dim R1 as Word.Range
Set R1 = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
R1.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "xxxx"
```

However, users may modify this template and possibly add other text boxes. How do I guarantee I'm addressing the correct text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find out what is the name of that textbox. For that you can use this code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shp
    Dim R1 As Word.Range

    Set R1 = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range

    For Each shp In R1.ShapeRange
        Debug.Print shp.Name
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Once you know the name then simply use that name

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim R1 As Word.Range

    Set R1 = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range

    R1.ShapeRange("Text Box 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "xxrrrxx"
End Sub
```

This way even if new shapes will be added your code will always write to the correct textbox.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What property of the textbox returns the name "text box 1"?

Comment: I'm an idiot. I didn't see the first part of your answer. Thanks much!!